# using window.history.back() I have to click 4 times to return one page back

Tags: javascript, html

It sounds weird, but I have a back button that use JS method window.history.back(), all I want is to go back to the previews page. I noticed, when I click to see the customer's detail page, where my "back button" exist, if I click before loading the entire document, the button works OK,I mean, just one click, and it returns to the page I was before. But if I wait until the documento is full downloaded, it icludes 3 iframes , then I have to click on the "back button", 4 times to return one page.
This is the button code:

```
<a class='btn back pull-right' style='background-color: #45B6AF;color:#ffffff;'>Back</a>
```

I use the class back, and this is the JS part (extenal js file):

```
// go back to previous page
$(document).on('click', '.back', function () {
window.history.back();
```

});

Any ideas, I have been with this for two days !!!

Comment: Iframes can create new entries to the browser history. If you're setting the iframes through JS, try using something like `frame.contentWindow.location.replace`. If that's not what you're doing, post the iframe-related code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loading iframes shouldn't automatically add to browser history. You could search for occurrences of `history.pushState` to see if the code is explicitly adding to history.

As a hack, if your code executes before history is altered, you could do something like

```
let oldLength = history.length;

// go back to previous page
$(document).on('click', '.back', function () {
    let currentLength = history.length;
    window.history.go(oldLength - currentLength - 1);
});
```

Comment: Yes!, that was an excellent idea, problem resolved. I was missing that on iframes load, was affecting the history length,  thank you very much Jeril !